# How to create a Scala custom validator with Play2?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I wrote this excellent question:

[How to create a custom validator in Play Framework 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115106/how-to-create-a-custom-validator-in-play-framework-2-0)

The point is, the solution applies to the Java Play API.

How to write a custom validator in Scala ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `verifying` method on [Mapping](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Mapping).

For example:

```scala
Form("foo" -> text.verifying{ txt => txt.startsWith("bar") })
```

Comment: ok, maybe I did't ask my question properly... I want to define a validator as such: `val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "authtoken" -> authenticityToken
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)`

Comment: How to define this authenticityToken contraint/function/method or whatever it may be

Comment: I don’t think that’s currently possible because I guess you’d like to read the session and you don’t have access to it in validators.

Comment: well you have access to the session in java. I would think scala too