# How do I say that @ManyToOne is @Required in Play 2.0?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Consider a blog with the entities Post and Author. There is a ManyToOne relation between Post and Author:

```
@Entity
public class Post extends Model {
  @Required
  public String subject;

  @ManyToOne
  @Required
  public Author author;

  //...
}
```

Then, in the view:

```
@form(routes.Post.new()) {
  @inputText(postForm("subject"))
  @select(
    postForm("author.id"), 
    options(Author.options()), 
    '_label -> "Author",
    '_default -> "-- Select author --",
    '_showConstraints -> true
  )
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

When validating this field using a `Form<Post>` in a controller, the @Required constraint for the Author field is ignored when doing form.hasErrors().

How can I say that this field is required?

Comment: Paste a form element from your view which allow you to change the author of the Post.

Comment: Added the select field from the view.

Answer (score 1):

Your form by default passes `id` of the `Author` (or empty String if not selected) in such case your fastest solution will be:

```
if (postForm.hasErrors()
        || form().bindFromRequest().get("author.id")==null
        || form().bindFromRequest().get("author.id").equals("")) {

    return badRequest(postAdd.render(postForm));
}
```

eventually you can validate if Author object is reachable and return the error message if is not:

```
Author authorRef =
     Author.find.ref(Long.valueOf(form().bindFromRequest().get("author.id")));

if (postForm.hasErrors() || authorRef == null) {
    return badRequest(postAdd.render(postForm));
}
```

**Edit** Of course if you will not pass the field at all (for an example you'll remove the `@select{...}` from your view) the `@Required` constraint will catch that.

Comment: I've considered this, and of course this is a viable solution. However, this couples the controller too tightly to the model, and adds duplication for each field. Shouldn't this be a built-in feature in Play?

Comment: With this approach you don't need to set constraint in the model for relation field. Optionally can also search the web for writing custom validator ie http://stackoverflow.com/q/8115106/1066240 anyway I prefer my second suggestion - checking the ref in the controller, especially when using single action for different kinds of data saving. If you think that's missing feature you can send a suggestion to the Play's Lighthouse or pull request on the github