# Dynamic custom validation with Play framework 2.2.x

Tags: java, html, validation, scala, playframework-2.0

This post makes it easy to set up a custom validation tag using Play 2.1(or 2).x "[How to create a custom validator in Play Framework 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115106/how-to-create-a-custom-validator-in-play-framework-2-0)". My use case, however, is a little different and I am hoping for a UI Play Framework Jedi Master that can provide some sort of direction. We have the normal MVC pattern to create reports, and for most scenarios, having validation in the play model using custom tags works fine. One of our use cases, however, is for custom "dynamic" validation. If we use the "Required" case, as an example, its easy to say that when form ABC loads, then fields X, Y and Z are required - But what if you dont know the list of required fields until just before the form is rendered and the list of required fields is provided to you in a json file from a db read in the controller. How, then, would you cater for this with the Play framework?

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution but without annotation. Create a validate method on your form (see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms)

You'll be able to do all the checks you want there.